# How to model a mixture of 3 Normals in PyMC?

Tags: pymc, mixture-model

There is [a question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46626/fitting-model-for-two-normal-distributions-in-pymc) on how to use PyMC to fit two Normal distributions to data. The answer of [Cam.Davidson.Pilon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11867/cam-davidson-pilon) was to use a Bernoulli distribution to assign data to one of the two Normals:

```py
size = 10
p = Uniform( "p", 0 , 1) #this is the fraction that come from mean1 vs mean2
ber = Bernoulli( "ber", p = p, size = size) # produces 1 with proportion p.
precision = Gamma('precision', alpha=0.1, beta=0.1)

mean1 = Normal( "mean1", 0, 0.001 )
mean2 = Normal( "mean2", 0, 0.001 )

@deterministic
def mean( ber = ber, mean1 = mean1, mean2 = mean2):
    return ber*mean1 + (1-ber)*mean2
```

Now my question is: how to do it with **three** Normals?

Basically, the issue is that you can't use a Bernoulli distribution and 1-Bernoulli anymore. But how to do it then?

---

**edit:** With the CDP's suggestion, I wrote the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc as mc

n = 3
ndata = 500

dd = mc.Dirichlet('dd', theta=(1,)*n)
category = mc.Categorical('category', p=dd, size=ndata)

precs = mc.Gamma('precs', alpha=0.1, beta=0.1, size=n)
means = mc.Normal('means', 0, 0.001, size=n)

@mc.deterministic
def mean(category=category, means=means):
    return means[category]

@mc.deterministic
def prec(category=category, precs=precs):
    return precs[category]

v = np.random.randint( 0, n, ndata)
data = (v==0)*(50+ np.random.randn(ndata)) \
       + (v==1)*(-50 + np.random.randn(ndata)) \
       + (v==2)*np.random.randn(ndata)
obs = mc.Normal('obs', mean, prec, value=data, observed = True)

model = mc.Model({'dd': dd,
              'category': category,
              'precs': precs,
              'means': means,
              'obs': obs})
```

The traces with the following sampling procedure look good as well. Solved!

```py
mcmc = mc.MCMC( model )
mcmc.sample( 50000,0 )
mcmc.trace('means').gettrace()[-1,:]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is a `mc.Categorical` object that does just this.

```py
p =  [0.2, 0.3, .5]
t = mc.Categorical('test', p )
t.random()
#array(2, dtype=int32)
```

It returns an int between 0 and `len(p)-1`. To model the 3 Normals, you make `p` a `mc.Dirichlet` object (it accepts a `k` length array as the hyperparameters; setting the values in the array to be the same is setting the prior probabilities to be equal). The rest of the model is nearly identical.

This is a generalization of the model I suggested above.

---

Update:

Okay, so instead of having different means, we can collapse them all into 1:

```py
means = Normal( "means", 0, 0.001, size=3 )

...

@mc.deterministic
def mean(categorical=categorical, means = means):
   return means[categorical]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about the categorical and dirichlet, what confuses me is what to put in the line of `return ber*mean1 + (1-ber)*mean2`. I updated the question with a proposal, can you tell me if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: Alright, that does help. I added a full code example that I came up with with your help, but it still doesn't converge the way it should.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I thought the implementation was still wrong but it turns out it was the sampling. Fitting works with the above code, thank you very much! :)