# Bayesian Correlation using PyMC

Tags: correlation, bayesian, pymc

I'm pretty new to PyMC, and I'm trying to implement a fairly simple Bayesian correlation model, as defined in chapter 5 of ["Bayesian Cognitive Modeling: A Practical Course"](https://webfiles.uci.edu/mdlee/LeeWagenmakers2013_Free.pdf), which is as defined below:

[image: Graphical model]

I've put my code in an ipython notebook [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/tdiethe/sandbox/blob/master/bayesian_correlation.ipynb), a code snippet is as follows:

```
mu1 = Normal('mu1', 0, 0.001)
mu2 = Normal('mu2', 0, 0.001)
lambda1 = Gamma('lambda1', 0.001, 0.001)
lambda2 = Gamma('lambda2', 0.001, 0.001)
rho = Uniform('r', -1, 1)

@pymc.deterministic
def mean(mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2):
    return np.array([mu1, mu2])

@pymc.deterministic
def precision(lambda1=lambda1, lambda2=lambda2, rho=rho):
    sigma1 = 1 / sqrt(lambda1)
    sigma2 = 1 / sqrt(lambda2)
    ss1 = sigma1 * sigma2
    ss2 = sigma2 * sigma2
    rss = rho * sigma1 * sigma2
    return np.power(np.mat([[ss1, rss], [rss, ss2]]), -1)

xy = MvNormal('xy', mu=mean, tau=precision, value=data, observed=True)

M = pymc.MCMC(locals())
M.sample(10000, 5000)
```

The error I get is "error: failed in converting 3rd argument `tau' of flib.prec_mvnorm to C/Fortran array"

I only found one other reference to this error (in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790128/how-to-code-a-hierarchical-mixture-model-of-multivariate-normals-using-pymc)) but I couldn't see how to apply the answer from there to my code.

Comment: I have no idea neither about Python nor Bayesian statistics, but this seems like a runtime problem somewhere deep in the code. You can probably do nothing about it, but you may want to report the issue to the package developer(s) and seek their advice.

Comment: The problem with migrating it, is that after Abraham D Flaxman's partial answer, this is now definitely a Bayesian modelling issue, and not a coding issue ... unlikely to get an answer here.

Comment: Argh. The developers should have provided an informative error message. That an input matrix has wrong dimensions is something very easy to check, and they should have done this.

Comment: I guess this might not be relevant anylonger, but I have found your main issue. Instead of ```ss1 = sigma1 * sigma2``` you should write ```ss1 = sigma1 * sigma1```. Unfortunately, the results still are not "correct" all the time somehow.

Comment: @barsch good spot! I've updated the notebook to reflect this. The rho values seem to be pretty wild as you say.

Comment: For some sample data it works perfectly, but for some not. I am using another prior for sigma though as I am not sure whether you are doing the inverse Gamma the right way. Also, you are missing the inverse of the covariance matrix at the end. The accepted answer is wrong in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uninformative error is due to the way you have organized your data vector.  It is 2 rows by `n` columns, and `PyMC` expects it to be `n` rows by 2 columns.  The following modification makes this code (almost) work for me:

```
xy = MvNormal('xy', mu=mean, tau=precision, value=data.T, observed=True)
```

I say almost because I also changed your precision matrix to not have the matrix power part.  I think that the `MvNormal` in your figure has a variance-covariance matrix as the second parameter, while `MvNormal` in `PyMC` expects a precision matrix (equal to the inverse of `C`).

[Here is a notebook which has no more errors](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/1a6e03bcc19f481c6312), but now has a warning that requires additional investigation.

Comment: I've marked it as accepted, since you fixed the bugs (thanks!), but I'm still not getting reasonable results

Comment: try another question, then...  this should be do-able. To address the warnings, I would look at the initial values for lambda. Also `ss1` might not be defined as you intended, and the parameter for `mu` is precision, not variance.

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamDFlaxman The link to the notebook doesn't work or stopped working. Any chance we can bring it up again?

Comment: maybe a glitch in nbvviewer?  it is working for me now.